# Writing HTML for a string of values using javascript and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to have my page's html to appear as:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='domain-list0'>Hello</div>
  <div class='domain-list1'>World</div>
</div>
```

Here is my html and js: [Pen from Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/spikeyty/pen/58828a66e1d118a762ad480ff8964706)

Instead of creating the first "domain-list" and then creating another one for the next, it is just overwriting the previous "domain-list". This is why it shows the last string value. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which removes the existing content, and replaces it with the new content. You need to use append so that the new content is added after the last child.

```
var myStringArray = ["Hello", "World"];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var $el = $("<div  />", {
        'class': 'domain-list' + i,
        html: "<p>" + myStringArray[i] + "</p>"
    }).appendTo("div.container");
    // $el refer to the newl added element
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V4Vm7/)

- use [.appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) so that it will return the newly created element which can be used for further processing

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  $("div.container").html("<div class='domain-list'></div>");
  $(".domain-list:nth-child("+i+")").html("<p>"+myStringArray[i]+"</p>");
  //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use appendTo in jquery

```
var myStringArray = ["Hello","World"];
var arrayLength = myStringArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  $("<div class='domain-list"+i+"'></div>").html("<p>"+myStringArray[i]+"</p>").appendTo("div.container");
  //Do something
}
```